# My query runs in terminal but giving syntax error inside a Javascript procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query that runs fine when ran in terminal. But when I add it in a javascript snowflake procedure, its giving me an error.
The query:
`SELECT replace('[[:space:]]+('||listagg(keyword, '|')||')[[:space:]]+', '\\', '\\\\') as pattern FROM qwerty;`

The error:
`SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 79 unexpected '\\'. parse error line 3 at position 8 near '<EOF>'.`

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript escapes backslashes. So does Snowflake. This means that when you put backslashes in a JavaScript SP in Snowflake, you need to double escape them. Try this:

```
SELECT replace('[[:space:]]+('||listagg(keyword, '|')||')
[[:space:]]+', '\\\\', '\\\\\\\\') as pattern FROM qwerty;
```